# How to restore the pause time of vimeo on page reload using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I'm trying to create a jquery script to store the pause time of vimeo video so that when he comes back he can watch it from where he left off

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    player.on('pause', function() {
        console.log("pause");   
    });
});
```

I want to achieve this using local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already figured out what bricks you needed, now you just need to put them together.

With the [Vimeo Player API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js), you can fetch the vimeo instance and [get the player time](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#getcurrenttime-promisenumber-error) [when the video pauses](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#pause-promisevoid-passworderrorprivacyerrorerror).

Then use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to [store the data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

When loading the page, just [check localStorage if data is present](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and use the Vimeo Player API again to [set the current time](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#setcurrenttimeseconds-number-promisenumber-rangeerrorerror) if so.

```
let time = localStorage.getItem('videoProgress');
if(time != null) {
    player.setCurrentTime(time);
}

player.on('pause', function() {
    player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
        localStorage.setItem('videoProgress', seconds);
    });
});
```